# Longest Common Subsequence of Three Sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x

I've implemented my version of Longest Common Subsequence of Three Sequences and cannot find a mistake. But Coursera grader says that I fail last test case.
It means that the algorithm is almost corrects but outputs a wrong answer in a **specific** case. But what case is it?

**Constraints**: length of the list is not less than one and not bigger than 100. Numbers in the lists are integers from -10^9 to 10^9.

```
import sys


def lcs3(a, b, c):
    start_b = 0
    start_c = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(start_b, len(b)):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                for k in range(start_c, len(c)):
                    if b[j] == c[k]:
                        start_b = j+1
                        start_c = k+1
                        result.append(a[i])
                        break
                if b[j] == c[k]:
                    break
    return len(result)


def lcs3_reversed(a,b, c):
    # check reversed sequence which can be with different order
    a_rev = a[::-1]
    b_rev = b[::-1]
    c_rev = c[::-1]
    result = lcs3(a, b, c)
    result_reversed = lcs3(a_rev, b_rev, c_rev)
    if result == result_reversed:
        return result
    else:
        return result_reversed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    an = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    a = data[:an]
    data = data[an:]
    bn = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    b = data[:bn]
    data = data[bn:]
    cn = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    c = data[:cn]
    print(lcs3_reversed(a, b, c))
```

**Update:** added the function *lcs3_reversed* to solve the cases described by you. Anyway cannot pass the test case.

Output should contain the length of common subsequence. For example, for input:

```
3
1 2 3
3
2 1 3
3
1 3 5
```

output is **2** because the common part is (1, 3) for these 3 lists.

Runtime for failed case is 0.04 seconds and it looks like that the lists are rather long since most of my own tests worked much faster.

Thanks for your help!

**Update2:** I've tried another version. First we find the Longest Common Subsequence of 2 lists and then use it again on our result and the 3-rd list.

```
def lcs2(a, b):
    start_b = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(start_b, len(b)):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                start_b = j+1
                result.append(a[i])
                break
    return result


def lcs2_reversed(a, b):
    # check reversed sequence which can be with different order
    a_rev = a[::-1]
    b_rev = b[::-1]
    result_reversed = lcs2(a_rev, b_rev)[::-1]
    return result_reversed

def lcs3_reversed(a, b, c):
    lcs2_str = lcs2(a, b)
    lcs2_rev = lcs2_reversed(a, b)
    lcs3_str_str = lcs2(lcs2_str, c)
    lcs3_rev_rev = lcs2_reversed(lcs2_rev, c)
    lenghts = [len(lcs3_str_str), len(lcs3_rev_rev)]
    return max(lenghts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    an = input()
    a = input().split()
    bn = input()
    b = input().split()
    cn = input()
    c = input().split()
    print(max(lcs3_reversed(a, b, c), lcs3_reversed(a, c, b), lcs3_reversed(b, a, c),
              lcs3_reversed(b, c, a), lcs3_reversed(c, a, b), lcs3_reversed(c, b, a)))
```

Moreover, I tried all the combinations of orders but it did not help... Again I cannot pass this last test case.

Comment: use raw_input()  on PY2 or input() on PY3, not sys.stdin.read(). Also, do not user input as variable name, this is a python function

Comment: Your code can get the wrong answer if there are multiple subsequences. Consider `lcs3([1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,1,2], [1,3,4,5,2])`. Your code will return `2`, which is the length of the `[1,2]` subsequence. It ignores the longer `[3,4,5]` subsequence.

Comment: Apero, why shouldn't I use sys.stdin.read()? It is a very simple way to read multiple lines input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example breaks with something like:

```
a = [1,2,7,3,7]
b = [2,1,2,3,7]
c = [1,2,3,1,7]
```

The sequence should be `[1,2,3,7]` (if I understand the exercise correctly), but the problem is that the last element of `a` gets matched to the last elements of `b` and `c`, which means that `start_b` and `start_c` are set to the last elements and therefore the loops are over.